# How do you properly change a model in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the below two models, and am trying to change the userId property on the Report model to not have to be unique. When I change unique to false, or delete the property altogether, I am still getting the unique validation error when trying to create a Report with an existing userId (using `models.Report.create({ userId: 1 })` when 1 is an existing user's id). I've also tried making a migration and running that to no avail.

Am I missing something here? Been stuck on this for a while, so any input is massively appreciated. Thank you.

**Report.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Report = sequelize.define(
    'Report',
      userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,       
        unique: true,
      },
  );

  Report.associate = function(models) {
    Report.belongsTo(models.UserInfo, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
  };
  return Report;
};
```

**UserInfo.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const UserInfo = sequelize.define(
    'UserInfo',
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
  );

  UserInfo.associate = function associate(models) {
    ApplicantInfo.hasMany(models.Report, { foreignKey: 'applicantId' });
  };

  return ApplicantInfo;
};
```

Comment: What exact error did you get? Also you should check out if uniqueness went off from a column in a DB.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting this error "error": "SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error". Not sure I follow - how do I check if uniqueness went off from a column in a DB?

Comment: After making the changes to the model, did you recreate or update the database with those changes?  There probably still a unique constraint on the database table's column.